# change all urls of images and link hrefs in laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

first our website url must be like this example.com
now our website url for laravel script is example.com/example 
I pass urls like this

```
<img src="/img/logo_min_white.png">
```

but I must pass url like this

```
<img src="/example/img/logo_min_white.png">
```

now I cant change all URLs 
how to do this automatic with laravel or htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building sites with `Laravel`, you should use `helpers` to generate links to other pages and resources. This way, you can easily change `assets` without having to change every page.
You can use a function like `asset` to fetch an image. This is relative to the folder specified in your application, which by default is `/public/`.

```
 asset("/my/image/location.png")
```

More about Laravel helpers: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset

If you are using a program like PHPStorm or Visual Studio Code, you can just use the find-and-replace function to replace all occurrences with a regex. You can find all occurrences of image tags with the following regex:

```
/<img src=("[/a-z_.]*")>/gim
```